# Two Problems with scroll bars in C#

Tags: c#, richtextbox

I hate two `richTextBoxs`.

I have two problems:

1. no matter how I define the scroll bar - it doesn't apear. if I write more than the length of the line - the cursor goes to the line below - I want everything to be writen in the same row and the user could move right-left with the scroll bar.
2. I want one scroll bar to control both richtextboxes.
   one horizontal for both, and one vertical for both.

Comment: And maybe a screenshot of your interface? I'm having trouble visualizing how your second request would look.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. You'll need to set the [`MultiLine`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.richtextbox.multiline.aspx) property to false (the default is true for RichTextBoxes) if you just want one line, or else set the [`WordWrap`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.textboxbase.wordwrap.aspx) property to false (this also defaults to true).
2. I guess you'll need to handle the [`HScroll`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.richtextbox.hscroll.aspx) and [`VScroll`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.richtextbox.vscroll.aspx) events of each RichTextBox, and in the event handlers scroll the other textbox by the same amount. Not sure how easy this would be, though...

Comment: The wordwrap wored - thanks :)
I figured as much about the mutual scorlling, but as you said - it's not eazy.

Comment: @Yarden - if this answer solved your problem, then mark it as accepted by clicking the check mark - under the down arrow by the answer's score. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Best way to solve your second Problem is to use GetScrollInfo and SetScrollInfo. I think you should be able to handle the `HScroll`and `VScroll`events, when they fire you'll have to set the new ScrollInfo in the second RichTextBox.

You'll need WM_SendMessage too for this job. (All usuable with imports of *User32.dll*)

Usual work to do:

Getting informed when the user scrolls (Scrollevents), and setting the new ScrollInfo to the second RichTextBox. After setting the ScrollInfo you'll need to send a Message to the Scrollbar / Control to Scroll.

First of all you need your "own" `SCROLLINFO struct`

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    struct SCROLLINFO
    {
        public uint cbSize;
        public uint fMask;
        public int nMin;
        public int nMax;
        public uint nPage;
        public int nPos;
        public int nTrackPos;
    }
```

Then get the Scrollinfo at ScrollingEvent in the first TextBox:

```
GetScrollInfo(this.Handle, SB_VERT, ref _si);
```

(where _si is your SCROLLINFO-instance). Then send the message to the scrollbar

```
    _si.nPos = 0815; //Your wanted new ScrollbarPosition (I think you can use the value of the first Scrollbar)
                //// Reposition scroller
                SetScrollInfo(Handle, SB_VERT, ref _si, true);

                //// Send a WM_VSCROLL scroll message using SB_THUMBTRACK as wParam
                //// SB_THUMBTRACK: low-order word of wParam, si.nPos high-order word of  wParam

                IntPtr ptrWparam = new IntPtr(SB_THUMBTRACK + 0x10000 * _si.nPos);
                IntPtr ptrLparam = new IntPtr(0);
                SendMessage(Handle, WM_VSCROLL, ptrWparam, ptrLparam);
```

Where `HANDLE` is the Handle of your RichTextBox that has to be scrolled - you can get the handle at anytime using

```
RichTextBox.Handle
```

You should really have a look at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb787537%28VS.85%29.aspx and http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms644950%28VS.85%29.aspx

There are also some good examples at pinvoke.net (for example  [GetScrollInfo](http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/user32.getscrollinfo))